# Erro ao criar extension para DataGridView C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, extension-method

Já utilizei extensions para outros componentes e não deu esse problema, está dando o **erro** apenas com o `DataGridView`. O componente acha a extensão, e não da erro, o erro apresenta apenas quando compilo projeto.

Ao compilar está dando o seguinte ***erro***:

> Error  1   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'ObterNomeDasColunas' and no extension method 'ObterNomeDasColunas' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\Nicola Bogar\Desktop\Sistema\MySolutionApp\WindowsFormsApplication3\frmCadastroPais.cs 55  38  WindowsFormsApplication3

```
public static class ExtensionsDataGridView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Obter os nomes das colunas da DataGridView.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dgv"> Grid.</param>
    /// <returns> Lista com os nomes das colunas. </returns>
    public static List<string> ObterNomeDasColunas(this DataGridView dgv)
    {
        List<string> lista = new List<string>();

        if (dgv == null)
            return null;

        if (dgv.ColumnCount > 0)
            for (int i = 0; i < dgv.ColumnCount; i++)
                lista.Add(dgv.Columns[i].Name);
        return lista;
    }
}

public class Teste
{
   private void frmCadastroPais_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
      dgv.DataSource = paisBindingSource.DataSource;

      List<string> lista = dgv.ObterNomeDasColunas();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu erro em questão, é que não está encontrado o `namespace` correspondente do método de extensão ou algum erro bem particular, então vou gerar um ***exemplo minimo*** para que você teste e tente resolver seu problema:

*Tente utilizar assim:*

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GridExtensions
{
    public static class Utils
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> GetNamesFromColumns(this DataGridView grid)
        {
            if (grid != null && grid.Columns != null && grid.Columns.Count > 0)
            {
                return (grid.Columns as BaseCollection)
                    .OfType<DataGridViewColumn>()
                    .Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>***Observação:*** não precisa muitas vezes gerar um `for` para extração de informações aonde a base são sempre coleções e o [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) pode auxiliar a montar uma nova lista.</sub>

---

```
using GridExtensions; // namespace respectivo do método de extensão...

public class Teste
{
   private void frmCadastroPais_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
      dgv.DataSource = paisBindingSource.DataSource;

      List<string> lista = dgv.GetNamesFromColumns();
   }
}
```

Comment: Resolvido amigo, estranho isso né, o seu código não mudou quase nada do meu, apenas a forma de obter o nome das colunas. Creio que realmente deveria ser algo relacionado a namespace.. Mesmo assim muito obrigado.